# VSCode Debug TypeScript files inside symlink project

Tags: node.js, typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am having a super annoying problem, that started unexpected.

I have two NodeJS projects, and both projects uses TypeScript and they are **symlinked**. I usually debug by just attaching to the running process.

When debugging with VSCode, if I put a breakpoint in the `projectA` it work just fine, and the breakpoint is bonded to the actual TS file I want.

But then, I need call `projectB` from my `projectA`, and here the debugger goes directly to the `projectA/node_modules/projectB/dist/**.js` files, and shows that my TS files are `breakpoint set but not yet bound`.

This is kind of unexpected, since it was working before, and the debugger went directly to the `projectA/node_modules/projectB/src/**.ts` files.

I am not sure what happened, but I don't recall changing anything, and I also can't make it work again.

If I try debugging with WebStorm (attaching, just like I do with VSCode) it works just fine, this is only happening with VSCode.

I even tried to install VSCode Insiders, but no luck.

**Node version**: 14.16.1

**launch.json**:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "Attach",
        "port": 9229,
        "request": "attach",
        "skipFiles": [
          "<node_internals>/**"
        ],
        "type": "node",
        "runtimeArgs": ["--preserve-symlinks", "--preserve-symlinks-main"],
      },
    ]
}
```

PS: Both projects has the `sourceMaps: true` defined in the `tsconfig.json` file